# Diagonalization of the inverse of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem with the diagonalization of the inverse of a matrix.

If the matrix $A$ can be diagonalized, then it is possible to write:
$$D=P^{-1}AP,$$ where $D$ is diagonal.

Therefore, if I take the inverse of each term I should get: $$D^{-1}=PA^{-1}P^{-1}$$ But my exercise book says that: 
$$D^{-1}=P^{-1}A^{-1}P$$ 
(the matrix $P$ stays the same, is not inverted).

Where is my mistake?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so you say that $(P^{-1}AP)^{-1} = PA^{-1}P^{-1}$. Well, let's check it out. If you are right, the two matrices will multiply to $I$, right?

OK, here we go:

$$(P^{-1}AP)\cdot PAP^{-1} = P^{-1} A P^2 A^{-1} P^{-1}... $$

now what?

---

Remember:

$$(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1} A^{-1}$$

You can also verify your book's solution:

$$(P^{-1}AP)\cdot (P^{-1}A^{-1}P) = P^{-1}A(PP^{-1})A^{-1}P = P^{-1}(AA^{-1})P=P^{-1}P = I$$

Comment: Thanks, I made a very stupid mistake

Comment: @FrancescoCaruso It happens to everyone. Think of it as a rite of initiation.

Comment: Ahaha will do! Thanks again

Comment: @FrancescoCaruso You know, if you get an answer you like, you can always upvote it, and you can (and shoul) also accept the answer you think is best.

Answer (score 2):

If $A=PDP^{-1}$ and $A$ is invertible (i.e. $0$ is not an eigenvalue), then $A^{-1} = (PDP^{-1})^{-1} = (P^{-1})^{-1}D^{-1}P^{-1} = PD^{-1}P^{-1}$

or equivalently stated

$P^{-1}A^{-1}P = D^{-1}$

Remember the "socks-and-shoes" property that $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}\neq A^{-1}B^{-1}$.

Putting on socks and then putting on shoes, if you want to undo the process you must first take off your shoes before taking off your socks.  You cannot take off your socks before taking off your shoes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer!!